# openacc - async - gaining speedup in data transfer when using many async queues

Tags: asynchronous, data-transfer, openacc

My question is regarding the effect of transferring more than one array in different async queues between host and device.

Assume we have four arrays:

```
double *a, *b, *c, *d;
```

And, each has been allocated with size of `N`.

```
a = (double*) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
b = (double*) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
c = (double*) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
d = (double*) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
```

Now, we can transfer them between device and host as following in **one clause**:

```
#pragma acc enter data copyin(a[0:N], b[0:N], c[0:N], d[0:N]) async
#pragma acc wait
```

Or, we can use **many async clauses** and transfer them on different queues:

```
#pragma acc enter data copyin(a[0:N]) async(1)
#pragma acc enter data copyin(b[0:N]) async(2)
#pragma acc enter data copyin(c[0:N]) async(3)
#pragma acc enter data copyin(d[0:N]) async(4)
#pragma acc wait
```

The outcome of both of above approaches is the same. However, performance-wise, the second one seems to be better in some cases.

I did some measurements and found that for `copyout`ing and updating host seems that using `more` than one queue is better than `one` in terms of performance.

Let's call the first approach `one`, and the second approach `more`, and following approach `more_nonumber` (notice no number for async clause):

```
#pragma acc enter data copyin(a[0:N]) async
#pragma acc enter data copyin(b[0:N]) async
#pragma acc enter data copyin(c[0:N]) async
#pragma acc enter data copyin(d[0:N]) async
#pragma acc wait
```

Then, here is the measurements for 10,000 iterations (excluding 100 first  and 100 last ones, leading to average of 9,800 iterations in between):

`one`

CopyIn: **64.273us**

Update device: **60.928us**

Update self: 69.502us

CopyOut: 70.929us

---

`more`

CopyIn: 65.944us

Update device: 62.271us

Update self: **60.592us**

CopyOut: **59.565us**

---

`more_nonumber`

CopyIn: 66.018us

Update device: 62.735us

Update self: 70.862us

CopyOut: 72.317us

---

Average of 9800 runs!

An speedup of 19% is observed for copyout (70.929/59.565) when using `more` method compared to `one`, or 14% for update self (69.502/60.592).

**My question:**
Are these numbers legitimate? Can we rely on these numbers?

For your convenience, I have put my code on the [github](https://github.com/milladgit/acc-mini-bench/tree/master/data-transfer). You can take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async is most useful when interleaving data movement and computation on the device.  Hence, this exercise is a bit extraneous but I'll do my best to explain what's going on.  I should note that this is how PGI currently (v16.10) implements "async" and not necessarily how other OpenACC implementations would implement "async".

By default, PGI uses a double buffering system to perform data transfers.   Since DMA transfers must reside in physical memory, the buffers are pinned.  The runtime copies the virtual memory to the pinned buffer, begins an asynchronous transfer of the buffer, then begins the virtual to pinned copy of the second buffer.  The buffers are filled and then transferred in turn until the full array is copied.  Note that each async queue will have its own buffers.

If you time your code without any async clauses, you'll see that putting the 4 variables in a single pragma is significantly faster that having each with their own.  The reason is that with 4 pragmas, the host waits until the last buffer is sent before moving to the next variable.  When they are all in the same pragma, once one array's last buffer starts it's transfer, the runtime can start filling the other buffer with the next array's data.

When you add "async" to the single pragma, followed by a wait, you should see no performance difference to that of not using "async" or "wait" at all.  In other words, these are the same:

```
#pragma acc update device(a,b,c,d) 

#pragma acc update device(a,b,c,d) async
#pragma acc wait
```

When you add "async" to the 4 individual pragmas, you'll get about the same performance as you would putting them all in the same pragma since the CPU doesn't wait to start buffering the next array.

I can't account for why the copy back (update self, copyout) from the device are faster when each array is on it's own async queue.  It seems to me that it wouldn't matter much.

For this test, the optimal would be to not use the double buffers and instead just pin the entire array in physical memory.  This way you'd save the cost of copying from virtual to pinned memory.  The compiler can't do this by default since physical memory is limited and it can't guarantee that the program's memory would fit.  For most codes where most of the time is spent computing on the device using pinned memory doesn't help much if at all.  Finally, there is some performance overhead to deallocation of pinned memory (the device needs to be synchronized to guarantee there's no transfer to the pinned memory).  Hence, it's most beneficial if the array is in a single data region but has many updates.

Here's the times using pinned memory:

```
% pgcc -fast -acc -ta=tesla:cc35,pinned transfer.c -o tpinned.out
% numactl -C 2 ./tpinned.out
one
CopyIn: 50.161us
Update device: 49.679us
Update self: 47.595us
CopyOut: 47.631us
---------
more
CopyIn: 52.448us
Update device: 52.135us
Update self: 49.904us
CopyOut: 47.926us
---------
more_nonumber
CopyIn: 52.172us
Update device: 51.712us
Update self: 49.363us
CopyOut: 49.430us
---------
```

Comment: Thanks again Mat for comprehensive response. On your system with pinned memory, **one** method is the winner. However, on my system, using pinned memory, **more** is better and gains more speedup! (PGI 16.5 - Geforce GTX 970 - CUDA 7.5 - CC 5.0) ---- I have another question regarding pinned memory: so, can we say if a program/algorithm is memory bound, pinned memory would help on performance since no extra memory operation is executed.

Comment: To me, memory bound means that the algorithm spends more time waiting for memory than it does computing thus causing the processor to idle.  What helps memory bound problems on a GPU is to add more threads so that while one thread waits for memory another can be running.   Not that pinned memory couldn't help a memory bound problem on the host CPU (no page swapping), in this context, I don't think the two are related so wouldn't make this correlation.